# Running top in Busybox

Tags: busybox

when I ran TOP command in Busy box, I just wanted to know if VSZ% is MEM%, if not how can get MEM% with TOP command in Busy box

Answer (score 0):

To understand this we need to first understand some other initialisms.

VSZ (or VIRT, depending on the version of top) is the amount of memory mapped into the address space of the process. It includes pages backed by the process' executable file and shared libraries, its heap and stack, as well as anything else it has mapped.
[-From a previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179655/how-to-interpret-busybox-top-output)

Busybox top shows the percent of virtual memory in use for a process as VSZ%, so you can see if something is over allocating memory on an embedded system, which may lead to problems down the line.

RES is important to understand, and straight from the manpage it is anything occupying physical memory.

Normally on non busybox systems %mem is RES / TotalPhysicalMemory

From a previous question:

> It looks like busybox top calculates %MEM as VSZ/MemTotal instead of
>   RSS/MemTotal.

[What do top's %MEM and VSZ mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44948/what-do-tops-mem-and-vsz-mean)

It looks like you can view more memory information by pressing "s" while inside busybox top, but I'm not sure you can see a column "%mem" by default with the busybox implementation.